# Error migrating Tridion 2009 Event System to Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion

After adding my existing Tridion 2009 event DLL's (compiled on 2011 server) to bin directory and registering DLL in Content Manager Config file the GUI now returns the error below. I have checked event logs, Tridion logs etc for more details on the 'missing dependency' anyone any ideas?

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Extensions.Events, Version=1.0.20.521,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ecb60dbe3cbb7440' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.

Unable to get LangID of User (tcm:0-2851-65552). Initialization of the extension
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\Tridion.Extensions.Events.MDO.dll' failed.

System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes(RuntimeAssembly,ObjectHandleOnStack) 
    System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.GetExportedTypes() 
    Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.LoadExtensions() 
    Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.LoadExtensions() 
    Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.TcmExtension.InitializeExtensions() 
    Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1,TcmEventArgs,EventDeliveryPhase) 
    Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IdentifiableObject,TcmEventArgs,EventDeliveryPhase) Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags,Boolean) 
    Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Load(LoadFlags) 
    Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.IdentifiableObjectFacade.Read(UserContext,String,XMLReadFilter) XMLState.GetPropertyElem XMLState.GetProperty User.LangID
```

Comment: Have you restarted all of the SDL Tridion Services, IIS and the relevant COM+ packages?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have two assemblies: `Tridion.Extensions.Events.dll` and `Tridion.Extensions.Events.MDO.dll`. Since you refer to TcmExtension DLLs by their full path in the Tridion.ContentManager.config, you cannot have one that depends on another in the same directory.

The solution is to put the "shared library" (probably `Tridion.Extensions.Events.MDO.dll` for you) in the GAC.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, .NET assemblies contain all the dependency information you need in their metadata. Faced with this problem, I would generally try to open up the assembly with a tool that can read this, for example, ILDASM, or IlSpy. That gives you a concrete list of things to look for, instead of the vague and mysterious "or one of its dependencies".

An alternative approach is to use FUSLOGVW to monitor where the .NET runtime is looking for assemblies.